# How do I change the Hot Word (wake word) on Google Assistant Raspberry Pi 3 (Non-AIY Kit)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, google-aiy

I've found some great tutorials around the internet on how to change the wake word on the AIY Kit for the Raspberry Pi ([Here's a good video of that](https://youtu.be/mETxgn0vH2I)), but cannot find one anywhere on how to change the hotword for a regular RPi 3 with the API setup.

I'm in the process of writing a [beginners' tutorial on this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E26n8fu0OmfGb6f7grQ0CRu76Yvyhk9B6clUhFtnQwQ/pub) and would love any and all advice on how to do this without the AIY kit. For reference and comparison, the AIY kit strategy is on that linked tutorial above in Part 5 using Snowboy's hotword creator.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use snowboy as long as you have some way of recording as a raw wav. I have done some work for the AIY Voice kit [Hotword and Voice Activation](https://danicymru.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/aiy-voice-kit-voice-vad-or-hotword-activation/) which may be of help. Basically get your audio into a queue in one thread and then take the audio off the other end and pass to snowboy. The activation is all done locally. Once activated you can carry on sending to Google. Hope this helps.